# Typo-tolerant text searching?

Tags: text, typography

I would like a search for `example` in text documents also to find:

- Exwmplw
- Eyanple
- rxsmple

`Test` should match:

- Twsz
- Trsr

#### What are ways to search text documents using typo-tolerance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a piece of software called [“*agrep*”.](https://www.tgries.de/agrep/agrephlp.html#AGREPMETASYMBOLS)
It stands for “Approximate – GNU Regular Expression Program”, but it is not a part of Linux distributions by default, although available in the official package repositories. 
You can download and install it instantly by typing `sudo apt install -y agrep` into your terminal.

The manual `man grep` mentions *“the variant programs egrep, fgrep and rgrep are the same as grep -E, grep -F, and grep -r, respectively.  These variants are deprecated, but are provided for backward compatibility.”*
**This is not the case with `agrep`** for the reason mentioned above (not precluded in Linux).

You can learn more about it on [it's Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/agrep)

Comment: `agrep` works relatively well, I find, except it won't cope with non-ASCII characters. You can work around that by increasing the tolerance level, but still it's a pity.